# Pegar nome da exceção em Python onde não está específico

Tags: exceção, python-2.7, socket

Estou usando a exceção `Exception`, mas queria ser mais específico e pegar a exceção correta, sem o tratamento o código me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> F:\Bel\Desktop\tpredes>guiCliente.py Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "F:\Bel\Desktop\tpredes\guiCliente.py", line 80, in enviar
>       self.test(True)   File "F:\Bel\Desktop\tpredes\guiCliente.py", line 77, in test
>       comunicacao.enviar()   File "F:\Bel\Desktop\tpredes\guiCliente.py", line 93, in enviar
>       s.connect((self.ip,self.porta))   File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) error: [Errno 10061] Nenhuma conexÒo p¶de ser feita porque a mßquina de destino as recusou
>   ativamente

Já tentei vários, mas não funcionam, também pesquisei sobre e não encontrei algo específico, será que a biblioteca que não criou exceções diferentes da mais geral, `Exception`?

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece-me que tem a haver com a conecção. Tente:

```
try:
   s.connect(('IP', 'PORT'))
except socket.error as exc:
   print 'Cautela: %s' % exc
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou certinho, você poderia explicar? o socket.error é provavelmente pq buscou na lib, mas e o as exc é uma área específica? Desde já agradeço sua atenção.

Comment: @ViníciusMarques `as` é para dar o nome que quiser só isso. Poderia ser ... `as YOO_MA_MEN:` se quisesse, e depois seria: `print 'Cautela: %s' % YOO_MA_MEN`